# Substring function does not work in Vb?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to mask SSn and want show it on label caption.

```
lblSPTINTo.Caption = rsMM("SPTIN")
lblCPTINTo.Caption = rsMM("CPTIN")
```

i am trying to use substring function to get last 4 characters but i not am to able to use it as it throws compile error .

```
lblSPTINTo.Caption = rsMM("SPTIN").sutbstring(4,4)
```

Comment: I don't see any code that uses `Substring`

Comment: Your use makes a substring from the 4th index and makes it 4 chars long. Where you need to get the length and -4 from that and not supply the second parameter.

Comment: Is that code VB6 or VB.NET?  A .NET `Label` control has no `Caption` property but I think a VB6 one does.  If the code is VB6 then that would explain why `Substring` isn't available.  If it's VB.NET then it's `Caption` that isn't available.  If it is VB.NET and you fix the compilation issue, it's still going to crash at run time.  You haven't got all that much going for that code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sutbstring` with `Substring`.

But it won't work that way because the first parameter is the index and the second parameter in `Substring` is the length, if you want the last 4 characters:

```
Dim last4 As String = rsMM("SPTIN")
If last4.Length > 4 Then last4 = last4.Substring(last4.Length - 4)
```

Comment: I'm sure that was a typo. From his edit you can see where they went wrong.

Comment: @OneFineDay: it may be a typo, but it  also caused the compiler errorOP has mentioned.